# SQL - How do I return the TOP 5 highest earning years?

Tags: sql

I have a `paystub` table in which the payroll records are recorded.

The fields related to this query are the `YearToDateGrossPay` and the `year`.

I need *to search through all the paystub records and **select the top 5 highest paid years***.

The last paystub of each year would tell me the final YTD amounts for that year and then I could select the top 5 of that subquery,  but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the subquery which selects the final YTD amounts, you can finish it off by

```
SELECT * FROM final_ytd_amounts ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC LIMIT 5
```

The ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC sorts the table by ytd_amount in descending order

The LIMIT 5 selects the top 5 rows only and chops everything else off

Comment: Hmmm, I will try it in Sql Server... Maybe wait for the DBMS ?

Comment: This is ok for MySQL but not in MSSQL. 

The equivalent code for this is `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM final_ytd_amounts ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC `

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, the above won't work.  In general, you should specify a particular database when asking a query.  In SQL Server, you can do:

```
SELECT top 5 *
FROM final_ytd_amounts
ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC
```

For completeness, the following is how you do this in Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM final_ytd_amounts
where rownum <= 5
ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM final_ytd_amounts 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5 
ORDER BY ytd_amount DESC
```